# Paypal Chained Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is there any way that I can programmatically check to be sure a customer's account is confirmed and is ready to receive payments in paypal?

Donations via our website always fail due to unconfirmed email of our primary receiver. I am using Paypal's Adaptive Payment (Chained Payment).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't specifically an API currently for confirming that a buyer account/email is confirmed.  What some merchants use as a work around for checking this is use the same API call that you are making, with a failure inidicating that it is not confirmed.